# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new in PHP and MySQL and I got a little problem with my project I'm working on.

Whenever I try to get data

```
$sql = "
SELECT s.id_study_group
     , s.id_schedule
     , m.name_major
     , s.class_
     , ts.name_subject
     , s.time
     , r.name_room
     , s.day
     , s.semester
  FROM tbl_schedule as s
     , tbl_major as m
     , tbl_room as r
     , tbl_subject as ts
 WHERE s.id_major = m.id_major 
   and s.id_subject = ts.id_subject 
   and s.id_room = r.id_room 
   and s.id_lecturer =".$this->session->userdata('id_lecturer');
```

but I get the following error message:

Error Number: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

which makes me confused is:
the first time I run this program the program works, then I do not change the code and I the run back this program I got error like this

Comment: var_dump($this->session->userdata('id_lecturer')); each time you run the query and see if it is null

Comment: change it to prepared statement

Comment: not effect still got error

Comment: Edited for readability. The error occurs at a different line number now. Echo the query. The error will be obvious. Oh and we stopped writing queries ca. 1992. Come. JOIN us.

Answer (score 1):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3

Put quote, so that you may not run into syntax error, if `$this->session->userdata('id_lecturer')` returns null

**From**

```
s.id_lecturer=".$this->session->userdata('id_lecturer');
```

**To**

```
s.id_lecturer='".$this->session->userdata('id_lecturer')."'";
```

So it becomes like below, if you use heredoc,  heredoc syntax is much cleaner and it is really useful for multi-line strings to avoid quoting issues, you can also use [**`active_record`**](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) :

```
$lect_id = $this->session->userdata('id_lecturer');
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT s.id_study_group,
       s.id_schedule,
       m.name_major,
       s.class_,
       ts.name_subject,
       s.time,
       r.name_room,
       s.day,
       s.semester
FROM 
       tbl_schedule as s, 
       tbl_major as m, 
       tbl_room as r, 
       tbl_subject as ts
WHERE 
       s.id_major=m.id_major and 
       s.id_subject=ts.id_subject and 
       s.id_room=r.id_room and  
       s.id_lecturer="$lect_id"
SQL;
```

Comment: i try for this code is work but no get a data, in before error I got the data you know why ? or my sql is wrong ?

Comment: @HendrayanaFauzi your `$this->session->userdata('id_lecturer')` was  returning null probably so

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
$sql = "SELECT s.id_study_group,s.id_schedule,m.name_major,s.class_,ts.name_subject,s.time,r.name_room,s.day,s.semester
        FROM tbl_schedule as s, tbl_major as m, tbl_room as r, tbl_subject as ts
        WHERE s.id_major=m.id_major and s.id_subject=ts.id_subject and s.id_room=r.id_room and s.id_lecturer='".$this->session->userdata('id_lecturer')."'";
```

Comment: i try for this code is work but no get a data, in before error I got the data you know why ? or my sql is wrong ?